# replace specific fields in multiple csv files and save the files again using R

Tags: r, csv, replace, lapply

I am relatively new to R and this is my first ever question here, sorry if I miss to report something.

What I want to do is read in multiple csv files. The trick is that the first 3 rows need to stay intact and the actual header is in row 3. I only need to change 2 values, 29 and 47 to Si29 and Ti47 and get rid of some NA that R adds (I do not understand why).

If I would do that for 1 file I got

```
read_data<-read.delim(file.choose(), header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE, sep=",")

read_data[3,7]="Si29"
read_data[3,11] ="Ti47"
read_data[1,7]=""
read_data[2,7]=""
read_data[1,11]=""
read_data[2,11]=""

write.csv(read_data,"610_01x.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

However, I have hundreds of files where I need to make the exact same operation and save the files again.

I understand how to read in multiple files, and also got it to work that they are saved again as separate files, but I am at a complete loss on how to change only specific fields in each file:

```
file_list   <- list.files(wd, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
#this command creates a separate data frame for each file and makes sure the first 3 rows stay intact as in the original
myfiles = lapply(file_list, read.delim, sep = ",",check.names=FALSE, header=TRUE)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `header=TRUE` is a problem because that is not the true column names (in row 3) and it is interfering with how you are referencing the "cells" in your table. i.e.
`data[row_numbers, column_numbers]` is not where you want to be. The column names it is picking up will be from the first line(s) you do not want "touched". Additionally, column names will also not be part of your "tables" true reference positions. Try `header=FALSE`

Also, it is usually better practice to use `read_data[3,7] <- "Si29"` instead of `=` for assigning values, whereas `=` is usually used for binding inside of functions (it's a long story I don't fully get)

*EDIT* Oh I see what you are saying.

You need to make a function for 'lapply' to do all the things you want in one go. Hard to test without your data, but something like this:

```
doTheThing <- function(){
read_data <- read.delim(file.choose(), header=FALSE, check.names=FALSE, sep=",")
read_data[3,7]="Si29"
read_data[3,11] ="Ti47"
read_data[1,7]=""
read_data[2,7]=""
read_data[1,11]=""
read_data[2,11]=""
}

myfiles = lapply(file_list, doTheThing())
```

Then write all the files out from the `myfiles` again.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the first part. I still do not understand, however, how I can apply the same changes to a multitude of files.

Comment: Are the problem data "cells" always in the same position?
Or are they always change any 29 to Si29 in any position always, and remove any NA and replace with "", and leave other instances throughout the data untouched?

Comment: thanks for the additional information provided in the answer. yes they are always in the same position. I want to specifically change one 29 in the dataset to Si29. Same for removing NA, always the same cell in every sheet, leaving everything else untouched.